# Convert Blob URL to file object with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch-api

I have an image cropper that creates a blob file for each crop.

When the user finished cropping he clicks a success button and I get an URL that looks like this:
blob:https://localhost:5001/4434606b-29c4-483d-a1fc-1cefe50a3e3a". Since I need a file object (so I can post it to my server) I convert this blob into an actual file object with this code:

```
const file = await fetch(blobUrl).then(r => r.blob()).then(blobFile => new File([blobFile], fileName, { type: blobFile.type }));
```

This code works, but unfortunately, I need to provide IE11 support and since fetch is not supported (and polyfills don't seem to work for this fetch call) I would like to migrate this statement into axios (which I already use all over my application).

This is what I've tried:

```
axios.get(blobUrl).then(r => r.blob()).then(blobFile => new File([blobFile], fileName, { type: blobFile.type }));
```

When I look at the response from the first call (`then(r => r.blob()`) I get something like this:
[image]

I assume this is because the image can't be displayed in the console, but when I try to call "r.blob()" I get this:

> r.blob is not a function

**How can I change my axios call to work like the fetch call above?**

Side note: I don't know which file type my response will have (except that it's an image), so it could be a png, jpg, gif etc.

Comment: plese check with const imageUrl = '';
axios({
    url: {imageUrl},
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'blob', // important
  })

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Apparently what I tried was a bit overkill. Here's the solution that worked for me:

```
const config = { responseType: 'blob' };
axios.get(blobUrl, config).then(response => {
    new File([response.data], fileName);       
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: not working to me, always get Network Error

Answer (score 8):

set axios header :

```
axios.get(blobUrl, {
       responseType: 'blob'  /* or responseType: 'arraybuffer'  */         
})
.then(r => r.blob())
.then(blobFile => 
     new File([blobFile], fileName, { type: blobFile.type })
);
```

Comment: It's always return Network error to me