# How to convert image "blob:http://localhost...." to File in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-easy-crop (https://github.com/ricardo-ch/react-easy-crop) to crop the image and post cropped images to API
After cropping the image, I have an image like this

```
blob:http://localhost:3000/f9cd925a-89ec-4eb7-a170-2274e5ea1958
```

My API to post an image with File type, so I try to convert to File like this

```
const blobToFile = new File([croppedImage], 'imageCrop.jpg', {
        lastModified: new Date().getTime(),
        type: croppedImage.type,
      })
```

blobToFile that I received

```
File {name: "imageCrop.jpg", lastModified: 1619259461151, lastModifiedDate: Sat Apr 24 2021 17:17:41 GMT+0700 (Giờ Đông Dương), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 63, …}
```

But blobToFile that I received can't POST to my API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem in this [Convert Blob URL to file object with axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59465413/convert-blob-url-to-file-object-with-axios)

```
const file = await fetch(blobUrl).then(r => r.blob()).then(blobFile => new File([blobFile], fileName, { type: blobFile.type }))
```

Comment: works fine. saved the day!

Answer (score 0):

use below one to convert blob to file.

```
var file = new File([blob], "filename");
```